# Download Apple developer videos for offline usage

Tags: ios, video, data-transfer

I would like to download Apple developer videos https://developer.apple.com/videos/ they release each year to watch them at double speed or to watch them offline. I am a registered developer with full access. Just right clicking and hitting download doesn't work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the video from the intro page (e.g. [WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2015/)). At the bottom of each (streaming) video switch to "Resources" and download the linked HD/SD mp4 video:

[image]

A developer account or an Apple ID is not needed.

Comment: It is now under Overview. There is no longer a separate Resources tab.